# Multiple buttons on right hand side of Header

Tags: header, jquery-mobile

I would like to have more than one button on the right side of the Header bar.  The [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html) say you can customize using a DIV, but when I do that the buttons do not have their normal style.  Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've seen this done in the footer ([Shown Here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/docs-footers.html)), might give you an idea for the header or toolbar

Answer (score 33):

The above example puts more than buttons on the header but they are all positioned to the left of the header. I think you can group your buttons in a controlgroup and position the control the group to the right of the header. Maybe something like this:

```
 
  <div data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right">  
     //have your button here
  </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do not forget to add the `data-role="button"` attribute to your anchor, so they render properly as button. (This is not necessary for standard Buttons in the header)

Answer (score 13):

This is how I did it, seems clean.

HTML

```
<div id="myHeader" data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <span class="ui-title"></span>
    <div class="ui-btn-right">
        <a id="myButton1" class="headerButton" href="#" data-role="button"></a>
        <a id="myButton2" class="headerButton" href="#" data-role="button"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.headerButton {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the grid class.

```
<div class="ui-grid-a ui-btn-right">
        <div class="ui-block-a" ><a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" >Button1</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b" ><a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" >Button2</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-icon-left 
    ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" data-rel="back" data-icon="cancel" 
    data-theme="a">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
      <span class="ui-btn-text">Cancel</span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-l ui-icon-shadow"></span>
    </span>
 </a>
```